# How to show default picture in display template if no picture found on the item?

Tags: display-template

I have cloned the OOTB displaytemplate "Item_PictureOnTop.html". I would like to show a default picture if the picture not found on the item. Is that possible with custom css?

[example here of current situation](http://s16.postimg.org/dut7xuwp0/disptemp.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your copy of Item_PictureOnTop.html you have to add some additional javascript logic to check if there is an image, and if not, insert something else.

An example could be

```
<!--#_

    // ...

    var noPictureFoundImgUrl = "url to image for no picture found"
    var imageUrl = null;

    if ($isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.ImageUrlColumn))
    {
        imageUrl = noPictureFoundImgUrl;
    }
    else
    {
        imageUrl = ctx.CurrentItem.ImageUrlColumn;
    }

    // then insert the 'imageUrl' variable in the markup

    // ...

_#-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniels solution checks for empty url, not if an image was *not* loaded.

I don't think you can do it with CSS since **onload** of an image is a JavaScript event.

There is no **notloaded** event

It requires some (minor) changes to the DisplayTemplate to do the opposite:

#### Reveal loaded images

- add an *onload* event to the image
- display your default IMG in a DIV with absolute position **on top** of the image
- in the *onload* that fires (for every image) remove the default IMG that is covering *this* image

That way you can also add fancy CSS animations

Als je er niet uitkomt, kun je me inhuren...

#### CSS only (by Jussi Palo)

You can achieve something with CSS only if you add:

```
.cbs-pictureOnTopImageContainer{
    background-image:url('/mydefaultimage.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

But the broken image indicator will be displayed

Comment: I stand corrected, you can also try the JavaScript *error* event on an image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript